# Largest detachable screen size

Tags: laptop, hdmi, tablet

Which are the laptop computers with the largest detachable screen sizes? I am looking for one such that I can take a 17" Full HD screen in my hands and use it as a tablet and use it to inspect the code as I walk, resting it occasionally on the desk to code with a keyboard.

Thanks.

Comment: To my knowledge I only know the surface book 2 has a 15" detachable screen.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by detachable? Would a 2 in 1 work for your user case scenario? Otherwise your search comes down to the largest possible tablet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm a bit confused because not all tablets are Windows 11 systems. Some just run Android. Thank you for your clarification. Thanks.